# How to handle a large number of activities in android studio

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, layout

Iam a student and Iam developing an app for my college for downloading previous year question papers,my college has 14 departments and for each department 8 semesters and in each semester minimum 10 subjects are there so 14*2*8= 1120 java files and XML files I have to create if I keep on intenting from one activity to another it will take a huge time.how handle this huge activities.my app structure would be
Select department(14) >> Select sem(8)>> select subject(10)
Is there any methods like nestedif or something else to reduce the activity files.if there are any methods please do help me to complete the project.thanks in advance

Comment: why do you need to create a Activity for each of these 1120 screens .,, Use Minimal number of Activities with Fragments also you can manage layouts by passing data between components  ..To getting start look for Android Fragment tutorials .

Comment: Thanks for the reply, iam a beginner so can u please share a sample code for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need that many activities.  You need to write abstract activities that take parameters and displays different data based on those.  At most I see 4 activities here-  department selector, semester selector, subject selector, and the actual subject activity.  And arguably some of those should be fragments instead, although that's more personal choice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, iam a beginner and  can u please share a sample code for this